# Shared tmux session as different users

Tags: tmux

We have been trying to create numerous shared Tmux sessions for various games on our server. A quick google showed up with solutions such as:

```
tmux -S /tmp/game new -s game
chgrp game /tmp/game
# then connect via
tmux -S /tmp/game attach -t game
```

This worked for the first game, but of course the shell remained that of the user that started the tmux instance. So we created a new user for each game.
We started the new tmux instance with:

```
sudo -u game tmux -S /tmp/game new -s game
```

That still worked, somehow, but it's getting sketchy. The problem we're facing now is starting a different shared instance to which people can connect via a `game.sh` script.

Doing

```
sudo -u othergame tmux -S /tmp/othergame new -s othergame
```

basically exits and does nothing. Trying to connect to it just shows `"failed to connect to server"`.

What are we doing wrong and, more importantly, is there some simpler way to do what we're trying to do?

Comment: See if the solution helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398850/create-new-tmux-session-from-inside-a-tmux-session

Comment: What kind of game or game administration task requires shared terminal sessions? Tmux isn't designed for shared session. I think you need to redesign your task or use different tools.

Comment: `tmux` does support shared sessions and AFAIK this is one of it's use-cases